# Get the coordinates of a touch and place a button on that position?

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am trying to get the coordinates from a touch but I can't figure out how.
I am in a view controller and I try to use the method `-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but I think it doesn't work with view controllers.
Am I right?

I just want to put a Button on the position I touched.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs in a View rather than ViewController, and would look something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)evt {
  UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
  CGPoint pt=[touch locationInView:self];
  // ...make your button at 'pt'...
}
```